# How to create relative mark positions in Vega LIte

Tags: vega-lite

I have a pie chart with width & height set to "container". I would like to label each slice of the pie. Therefore I included a layer and it creates the correct text. However, I don't know how to implement a relative radius size. How would you go about it?

With an absolute radius (e.g. 30) it works, but I need a relative position.

```
`"layer": [{"mark": {"type": "arc"}},
{"mark": {"type": "text", "radius":30},
"encoding": {"text": {"field": "*", "type": "nominal"}}
}]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create relative radii using an [Expression Reference](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/types.html#exprref) for the radius value.

For example, here is a chart where the radius of the pie chart is set to 40% of the chart size, and the text is set at 45% of the chart size (here I chose to measure the chart size as the minimum of the width and height, which seems reasonable for a circular chart):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius": {"expr": "0.4 * min(width, height)"}},
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": {"expr": "0.45 * min(width, height)"}},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ],
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```

[image]

([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUIHkbOoAnmggKEphEXBoYgC+CnEJZEmp6Ez+WZFoAGwFRZiJKWlQleHVqACMAAz1IPGNJc3oym3ZaADMfQNNZSA5me05qADs08WlaQBmYx0AHHkAugXzslBsyjSyZGig9HBBtyBbNoKj6FULIJjJOMsgAEcGEhZDogjpSP4IEEoABrNCYdSRPInDzJODqGKgZDqeEhb6-f72VpKdRIS4MCBPOAADxwmPQ3UoYkMACpDAgrgAKFzKegKQzwGhkLAAShAKKUcDOFyuN3x50ESSeL28736G2aSh+fzSsjYnNk4X8FjI0vesgYgkEKL6OLxd0JaUaNMw-jJFKp+Np9LSTLEAFY2Rzubz+YK4MKxRKTtLzpdrk8XW78aq3i1NaltU70PrDcbbYdMjYnE9oeo2LDlpbrSigA))